# Как проверить письмо?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отправляю через программу the bat
или MS Outlook

получаю - будто вставили в визуальный редактор (скрин)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="uk">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Письмо 1</title>
        
        
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">

    <table class="block" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;display: block;max-width: 600px;width: 100%;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
        <tr>
            <td class="block__item" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <a href="#" class="block__link" style="display: block;max-width: 165px;width: 100%;">
                    <img class="block__image" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" style="display: block;">
                </a>
             </td>
            <td class="block__item" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <img class="block__pic" src="img/roche.png" alt="roche" style="display: block;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="block__holder" style="border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
            <td class="block__text" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 1.5;color: #363636;padding-top: 22px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <span class="block__col" style="display: block;font-weight: 500;">Уважаемый[на] [пан/паны] [Name] [Last name],</span>спасибо за создание учетной записи пользователя<a href="#" class="block__site" style="color: #156db8;">test link</a>
                <span class="block__col" style="display: block;font-weight: 500;">Чтобы завершить регистрацию, нажмите на ссылку ниже:</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="block__elem" style="display: inline-block;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.2;color: #ffffff;background-color: #0066cc;border-radius: 4px;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;padding-left: 12px;padding-right: 12px;padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;">Окончить регистрацию</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="block__content" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 1.5;border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
               test, <span class="block__part" style="display: block;font-weight: 700;">Ваша команда test.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="block__desc" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 1.5;color: #363636;padding-top: 20px;">
                <span class="block__box" style="display: block;white-space: pre-line;font-size: 10px;line-height: 1.5;padding-bottom: 20px;">block,
            test tst
            E-mail: test</span>

                <span class="block__box" style="display: block;white-space: pre-line;font-size: 10px;line-height: 1.5;padding-bottom: 20px;">Примечание о конфиденциальности:
             Это сообщение предназначено только для использования указанным получателем (получателями) и может содержать конфиденциальную и/или конфиденциальную информацию. Если вы не являетесь целевым получателем, свяжитесь с отправителем и удалите сообщение. Любое несанкционированное использование информации, содержащейся в этом уведомлении, запрещено.</span>

                <span class="block__box" style="display: block;white-space: pre-line;font-size: 10px;line-height: 1.5;padding-bottom: 20px;">(&copy;) 2021 test company. Все права защищены.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Content-type: text/html` нужно выставить

Comment: @Pilaton, ничего не меняется. так пробовала <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content-type="text/html">

Comment: Вообще, `text/html` нужно выставить в приложении отправляющее ваше письмо, насколько я помню

Comment: @Pilaton, пробую, ничего не меняется...(

Comment: Попробуйте через thunderbird отправить. https://www.thunderbird.net/ru/

Comment: @Pilaton, тоже самое. может не так отправляю..

Comment: http://goodmails.ru/knowlage/kak-otpravit-html-pismo-cherez-thunderbird/

Comment: тут нужно что-то менять? такое впечатление, что я вставляю в визуальный редактор. По ссылке скрин  https://fv2-3.failiem.lv/thumb_show.php?i=dzv64jzze&view

Comment: Это визуальный редактор и есть.

Comment: @Pilaton, спасибо огромное за линк. вроде то что нужно

Comment: Так то, отправить html письмо можно практически в любом приложении, видимо вы код в визуальный редактор вставляли как раз-таки, или где-то нужно было принудительно указать, что письмо как html нужно отправить.

Comment: @Pilaton,  только проблема с картинками, странный путь. Не подскажете, как подправить? src="https:// ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/tUBy2qlV3Ewx803mJ1QPiZ4vxKrPrRAB8qsInc8TGzKEso9Q93o=s0-d-e1-ft#http://img/logo.png"

Comment: @Pilaton, а я прописала только src="img/logo.png"

Comment: Для отображения картинок, тот же гугл пропускает их url через свой домен, и чтоб они отображались, нужно чтоб у вас в письме они начинались с `https://...`

Comment: @Pilaton, спасибо, последний нюанс. а адапттив не подскажете, как делается? ведь медиазпросы недоступны..

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/englishdom/blog/340852/ ... https://habr.com/ru/company/netologyru/blog/324970/